Is there a way to take a lists first element of a list and make it the first items key and second element make it the first items value in python
I have come across a small problem when working on a particular programming exercise
In this exercise I am supposed to get data from a file which contains world series winning teams
example something like this:
1903 Boston Americans
1904 No World Series Held
1905 New York Giants
1906 Chicago White Sox
1907 Chicago Cubs

i thought of making it to a list first and then converting to a dictionary
something like this
This is how I created the list
with open('world_series.txt','r') as file:
winners=file.read()
line=winners.split('\n')
winner_list=[]
for i in line:
    parts=i.split(' ',1)
    winner_list.extend(parts)
print(winner_list)

D={1903 : 'Boston Americans',................}

so on and so forth
I dont know how to do it, if this method isn't a suitable method please do write a another suitable methods.

Please update your question with the code where you create the list first. It could be a trivial step to turn that into a dict.

If that's supposed to be the contents of some text file, just loop over each line, year, team = line.split(' ', 1), then D[year] = team…

@quamrana i have added the code of where i created the list

Mixing your split entries into the end of the list of lines isn't helpful. All you need to do is split each line, which gives you two values. Use one value for the key, the other for the value in your dict. That's all:
D = {}

with open('world_series.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        year, team = line.split(' ', 1)
        D[year] = team


Hi i am still not clear about your explanation if you can please try explaining it to me with a few more details i am new to python with just only 2 months into programming

I'm not sure what else needs explaining here, can you be more detailed? You can loop over each line in the file using for line in file. No need to read the entire file into a list and then do something with the list. So here line is one line of your file. You split that (you already have that part down it seems). Then you use these two values you get to set a key in a dict, which is what your end goal is.

it was a very helpful piece of code but i made a few tweaks to to it and was able to get the desirable results thank you very much
